# Angular 2. Bind data from directive to template

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

It's possible bind data from directive to template, where directive was add? For example I want display dirText:

[plunker][1]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div my-dir>Text from dir: {{dirText}}</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Its component text`
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-dir]'
})

export class MyDir{
  dirText: string;
  constructor(){
    this.dirText = 'Text from Dir';
  }
}
```

Comment: Closing it as the question is not meaningful.. you can use a component instead of directive. why  specifically you use `directive`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exportAs` property. It is name under which the component instance is exported in a template

**my.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-dir]',
  exportAs: 'myDir'
})
export class MyDir {
  ...
```

**parent.html**

```
<div my-dir #x="myDir">Text from dir: {{x.dirText}}</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4JrQdDw4OYBYXwFnQmNt?p=preview)**

Comment: the `exportAs` is used to provide a way to reference a directive **in a template**, correct? something like `<form #heroForm="ngForm"><input [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">...`. It doesn't provide any additional value inside the parent component instance since we can use `@ViewChild(MyDir)` even if the directive doesn't define `exportAs`?

Comment: Yes, that is. We can use `@ViewChild(MyDir)` without `exportAs`